# simpler way to check if two different strings are in a third string in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Here is my below code that works fine. `'cluster_name'` is a string variable that will hold some text.

```
if 'abc' not in cluster_name or 'xyz' not in cluster_name:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

i was looking to make the `if` condition even more simpler , something like this:

```
if 'abc' or 'xyz' not in cluster_name:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Watch out...They don't mean the same thing...

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks fine, but doesn't generalize well (imagine if you had to check ten substrings instead of just two). Try `any`.

```
substrings = ['abc', 'xyz']
if any(substr not in cluster_name for substr in substrings):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Comment: OP: Just to confirm, this only fails if both `abc` and `xyz` are present in `cluster_name`. Is this what you expect?

Comment: 'cluster_name'  will contain either 'abc' or 'xyz' at a time

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
print (re.search('abc|xyz',cluster_name) is not None)
```

is simpler. It does not need `if` or `else`; you can extend the search string as long as you want (although within reasonable limits, no doubt). `re.search` returns `None` if the regex does *not* match and you want the inverse of that, hence `not None`.